# android sqlite database running on emulator but not on mobile phone

Tags: android

Hlo! I made a contacts app which stores contacts using sqlite database. Earlier, it was running fine on both emulator & by installing its apk file in mobile phone. But then I ALTERed the database to add one more column to it, now it works fine on emulator but in mobile phone, no contact appears in the contacts' list.
I searched and tried alot but all in vain. 
So, if anyone could tell step-wise comprehensilvely what I should do, I'll be humbly grateful to them.
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: can you provide more detail of logcat or code ????

Comment: Do one thing first remove application from your mobile and then re-install it by APK , it will resolve your issue

Comment: Removing and Re-installing is not solving problem... tried it many times